# In VSCode how do you select a whole word with - in it?

Tags: text-editors, visual-studio-code

IE: say I double click `"LAYOUT:MENU-TRADE":` I want to select the entire constant. Or at least the entire `MENU-TRADE` part.

[image]

In atom I can accomplish this by removing `-` as an ignored character. How is this accomplished in VSCode?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Access in Settings the entry of
`editor.wordSeparators` whose default value is :

```
"`~!@#$%^&*()-=+[{]}\\|;:'\",.<>/?".
```

Remove the hyphen, so double-click will select hyphenated words.

Comment: The _Select Hyphenated_ extension is for Visual Studio, not VS Code.